# Login user from backend (firebase + node.js)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm looking for a way to send user's email and password from the client to my Firebase Backend Functions and make the login from the backend, I find out info about Id tokens and stuff like that, but I need just simple function that receives email and password and make the request to Firebase Auth.

On firebase late versions you might have something like **"signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)"**, So I'm looking the exact operation just for the SDK for node.js, and I dont seems to find one.

Thank you.

Comment: The Admin SDKs (including the one for Node.js) *never* supported signing a specific user in, as it goes against their purpose. Can you indicate which Node.js SDK you used in those earlier versions (a link to the site where you got it from would be great).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth only allows you to use signInWithEmailAndPassword on client side.

Comment: On earlier versions it work..., but I'm looking for parallel function, I mean do the same thing as signInWithEmailAndPassword()..

Answer (score 0):

You should not authenticate users on backend (although it's possible), because it might have unintended consequences, but you can authenticate user with `signInWithEmailAndPassword` on the browser and then verify "ID Token" to your backend.

#### Frontend (using `firebase`):

```js
const payload = {
  uid: user.id,
  idToken: await user.getIdToken()
}

//send payload to server
```

#### Backend (using `firebase-admin`):

```js
const decodedToken = await getAuth(app).verifyIdToken(body.idToken)
//check decodedToken.uid equals body.uid
```

You can read more into "ID token verification" here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#web

Comment: Huh.  You're saying you should not authenticate users in the backend?  That's the ONLY place you can authenticate users.